# module.xml org.jboss.Log4j.logmanager in Jboss 6.3 EAP?

Tags: java, jboss, module, cxf

I'm having a problem with one module of Jboss 6.3. This module is org.jboss.Log4j.logmanager. The server is stand up correctly, but when I try to call this web service give me next error.

[Problem when I try to call to Web Service with SOAP UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qYTy.png)

Attach the console server log,

```
 <i>12:27:57,739 INFO [org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap12FaultOutInterceptor] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8090-1) class org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap12FaultOutInterceptor$Soap12FaultOutInterceptorInternalapplication/soap+xml
12:28:51,531 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8090-1) Application {http://ws.gd.axa.com/Document}Document#{http://ws.gd.axa.com/Document}incomingDocuments has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The import org.apache.commons.io cannot be resolved
The import org.apache.log4j.Logger cannot be resolved
Logger cannot be resolved to a type
Logger cannot be resolved
FilenameUtils cannot be resolved
Logger cannot be resolved to a type
Logger cannot be resolved to a type
Logger cannot be resolved to a type
Logger cannot be resolved to a type
Logger cannot be resolved to a type
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:170) [cxf-api-2.7.11.redhat-3.jar:2.7.11.redhat-3]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.createFault(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:272) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.11.redhat-3.jar:2.7.11.redhat-3]
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:136) [cxf-api-2.7.11.redhat-3.jar:2.7.11.redhat-3]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:237) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.11.redhat-3.jar:2.7.11.redhat-3]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:69) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.11.redhat-3.jar:2.7.11.redhat-3]
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:75) [cxf-api-2.7.11.redhat-3.jar:2.7.11.redhat-3]
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58) [cxf-api-2.7.11.redhat-3.jar:2.7.11.redhat-3]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37) [cxf-api-2.7.11.redhat-3.jar:2.7.11.redhat-3]
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:107) [cxf-api-2.7.11.redhat-3.jar:2.7.11.redhat-3]
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272) [cxf-api-2.7.11.redhat-3.jar:2.7.11.redhat-3]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-api-2.7.11.redhat-3.jar:2.7.11.redhat-3]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:241) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.11.redhat-3.jar:2.7.11.redhat-3]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.11.redhat-3.jar:2.7.11.redhat-3]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.11.redhat-3.jar:2.7.11.redhat-3]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.11.redhat-3.jar:2.7.11.redhat-3]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.11.redhat-3.jar:2.7.11.redhat-3]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.11.redhat-3.jar:2.7.11.redhat-3]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.11.redhat-3.jar:2.7.11.redhat-3]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:262) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.11.redhat-3.jar:2.7.11.redhat-3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The import org.apache.commons.io cannot be resolved
The import org.apache.log4j.Logger cannot be resolved
Logger cannot be resolved to a type
Logger cannot be resolved
FilenameUtils cannot be resolved
Logger cannot be resolved to a type
Logger cannot be resolved to a type
Logger cannot be resolved to a type
Logger cannot be resolved to a type
Logger cannot be resolved to a type
at com.everis.ad10.business.services.IncomingDocumentsServiceImpl.<init>(IncomingDocumentsServiceImpl.java:23) [AD10_ApplicationServices.jar:]
at com.everis.ad10.ws.services.document.DocumentServiceImpl.incomingDocuments(DocumentServiceImpl.java:344) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:188) [cxf-api-2.7.11.redhat-3.jar:2.7.11.redhat-3]
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104) [cxf-api-2.7.11.redhat-3.jar:2.7.11.redhat-3]
<i/>
```

Attach the jboss-deployment-structure and the Jboss module of log4j,

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.jboss.log4j.logmanager">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="log4j-jboss-logmanager-1.1.0.Final-redhat-2.jar"/>
        <!-- Insert resources here -->
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.mail.api" optional="true"/>
        <module name="javax.jms.api" optional="true"/>
        <module name="org.dom4j" optional="true"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logmanager"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.modules"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Jboss module definition

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
        <deployment>
            <dependencies>

                <!-- Spring -->
                <module name="org.springframework.spring" >
                    <imports>
                        <include path="META-INF**"/>
                        <include path="org**"/>
                    </imports>
                </module>

                <!-- JBoss -->
                <module name="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
                <module name="org.jboss.as.server" />   
                <module name="com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj"/>             
                <module name="org.apache.xerces"/>
                <module name="org.apache.xalan"/>

                <!-- Oracle -->
                <module name="org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters"/>
                <module name="oracle"/>

                <!-- LIB -->
                <module name="javax.el.api"/>
                <module name="org.apache.commons.lang"/>

                <!-- CXF -->
                <module name="org.apache.cxf.impl">
                    <imports>
                        <include path="META-INF**"/>
                        <include path="org**"/>
                    </imports>
                </module>
                <module name="org.apache.ws.security"/>
                <module name="org.jboss.ws.api"/>

                <!-- Log4j -->

                <module name="org.jboss.log4j.logmanager"/>

                <!-- STF -->  
                <module name="org.apache.commons.collections"/>
                <module name="org.apache.commons.io"/>
                <!-- FW_SERVICES -->
                <module name="asm.asm"/>
                <module name="org.apache.commons.configuration"/>

                <module name="org.jacorb"/>

                <!-- FILENET -->

                <!-- Descomentar  -->
                <module name="filenet"/>

                <module name="org.jboss.client" slot="5.1.2"/>
                <!-- PROPERTIES -->
                <module name="com.axa.conf.fnfwd"/>
        </dependencies>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.picketbox" slot="main"/>
        </exclusions>               
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Thanks so much!